# Sanitizing output and formatting Jupyter notebooks files during git commits

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, bitbucket, githooks

I'm tying to write git hook that automatically sanitizes Jupyter Notebook outputes files using [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout) (you can see it as a source file formater).

That's needed because notebooks outputs can disclose confidential information that must not be committed. These portions to be stripped out are basically nodes in a JSON file.

I tried different hooks, but the pre-commit option is mainly used to [check if files are formatted](https://medium.com/zyseme-technology/code-formatting-scalafmt-and-the-git-pre-commit-hook-3de71d099514), and doesn't seem suited to iterate over the committed files and execute a command like `nbstripout`.

A bonus would be a hook that kept the original workspace files while formatting the committed files only on the remote repo (I don't even know if that would be possible due to potential conflicts).

Comment: Thanks @Yury Kirienko

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is a smudge/clean filter.  This is a way that you can have Git automatically convert files between the version that's checked in (the clean version) and the version in the working tree (the smudged version).

In your case, you'd want to set your smudge filter to `cat` (because you don't want to make a change) and your clean filter to `nbstripout`, assuming you can use that as a filter (from standard input to standard output).

This will make Git operate automatically on any files that are added, without the need to write a hook at all.  Note that you'll need to set the filter config on each system where you choose to work on this repo.

To do so, you'll need to set your `.gitattributes` file in the repo to process files with that filter:

```
*.ipynb filter=jupyter
```

and then set your filter settings:

```
$ git config filter.jupyter.clean nbstripout
$ git config filter.jupyter.smudge cat
```

and then run `git add --renormalize .` and commit.  The filter will not modify your workspace files unless you're checking out a branch that contains modified files, in which case you'll get the version in the repository (because the smudge filter is `cat`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `--renormalize` flag and must it be always included? It kind of makes it a bit less automatic.

Comment: The  `--renormalize` flag is only needed on the first time after adding the filters.  Its purpose is to run all files through the filters such that they will be normalized (i.e., run through `nbstripout`) even though they haven't otherwise been changed.  It isn't needed after that, provided you always properly configure the filters.